# Fabric : connect to machine with one user then do stuff with another

Tags: python, fabric

I'm currently trying to do the following using Fabric :

1. launch the command "whoami" as user "user1" on host
2. launch the command "whoami" as user "user2" on host

The corresponding Bach commands are :

```
$ ssh user1@host
  [...enter password...]
$ whoami
$ su - user2
  [...enter password...]
$ whoami
```

**Note that the only user allowed to connect to the host is "user1". I can't connect to my host using user2.**

I tried this Fabric code :

```
def mytask():
    with settings(user='user1', password='p1'):
        run('whoami')
        with settings(user='user2', password='p2'):
            run('whoami')
```

But it keeps asking me user2's password.

Answer (score 3):

Fabric can `sudo` to user, other than root:

```
def mytask():
with settings(user='user1', password='p1'):
    run('whoami')
    sudo('whoami', user="user2")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def mytask():
    with settings(user='user1', password='p1'):
        run('whoami')
        run('sudo -u user2 -S p2 whoami')
```

Comment: This didn't work as expected.It asks me for user2's password then it switches to interactive mode, the second "whoami" command isn't launched.

Comment: It keeps asking user2's password. (btw I'm sure the password is correct)